# Undefined Symbols For Architecture i386 during building linphone-iphone

Tags: ios, xcode7, sip, voip, linphone-sdk

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

"_eXosip_add_authentication_info", referenced from:

```
  _push_auth_to_exosip in liblinphone.a(sal_eXosip2.o)
```

"_eXosip_automatic_action", referenced from:

```
  _process_event in liblinphone.a(sal_eXosip2.o)
```

"_eXosip_automatic_refresh", referenced from:

```
  _sal_iterate in liblinphone.a(sal_eXosip2.o)
```

"_eXosip_build_publish", referenced from:

```
  _sal_publish in liblinphone.a(sal_eXosip2_presence.o)
```

"_eXosip_call_build_ack", referenced from:

```
  _call_accepted in liblinphone.a(sal_eXosip2.o)
```

"_eXosip_call_build_answer", referenced from:

```
  _sal_call_notify_ringing in liblinphone.a(sal_eXosip2.o)

  _sal_call_accept in liblinphone.a(sal_eXosip2.o)

  _sal_call_decline in liblinphone.a(sal_eXosip2.o)

  _call_message_new in liblinphone.a(sal_eXosip2.o)

  _process_refer in liblinphone.a(sal_eXosip2.o)

  _process_media_control_xml in liblinphone.a(sal_eXosip2.o)

  _process_dtmf_relay in liblinphone.a(sal_eXosip2.o)
  ...
```

I have already checked in Build settings, Build phases -> Link Binary With Libraries and other solution which but i am not able to solve this issue. Any Solution?